# Duplicate file when deploying apk

Tags: android, maven-2, jetty

This problem seems to come up for a few people, but I haven't been able to apply the solution suggested in other threads for one reason or another so...

I am trying to build a simple android app with an embedded webserver. The server of choice if jetty. I am using maven to manage dependencies with the maven-android-plugin. I have added jetty-server v8.x as a dependency with the default scope. When I try and deploy my apk to the sandbox I get an error

Found duplicate file for APK: about.html

So the file in question is from the jetty package, or rather it is found in two jetty packages, one being a dependency of jetty-server. Other threads out there seem to be suggest I delete the file from one jar or the other but this is not really a scalable solution as I am not the owner of the jars.

Is there a more general solution to this problem? Something that manages the conflict and build or deploy time?

I should note, I am a bit of a Java noob, and have gone the NetBeans and maven route because this is the toolkit I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, found it. The solution is to build using the following command

```
mvn android:deploy -Dandroid.extractDuplicates=true
```

Comment: Congrats on the solution.  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' by clicking the checkmark to the left.  This will show others that your problem has been solved.  Cheers~

Comment: @clumsyjedi I've been trying to fix my duplicate file problem also (settings.xml).  I converted to a maven project and built to a pom in the conversion, but in the third step of "http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/" I never got that error.  So instead I just tried to type your build command into the Maven console and nothing happened.  I'm really confused and just want this error to go away.  Any tips?  Thank you.

Comment: For me it doesn't help, even with <extractDuplicates>true</extractDuplicates> in pom.xml.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues:

First, to integrate Jetty, your project is going to need a pom.xml file. The Android APK (as-is) does not know how to resolve a pom with Maven dependencies without some sort of bridge.  So, you'll need to install a few plugins for Pom management onto Eclipse. Follow the instructions here: http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/
(I found it easier to create a new project using the method described here rather than converting my existing Android app to a Maven project, but I'm sure it'll work either way.)

Second, once you've installed this, you're going to have to make sure your pom.xml contains the necessary dependencies, build goals, and variables. So, open up your pom.xml, and make sure you have the following:

1. In the "build" node:

   sourceDirectory -> src

   defaultGoal -> install (I suppose...)
2. In the "dependencies" node:

   ... all the jetty/cometd dependencies (org.cometd.java, org.eclipse.jetty, etc.)

Third, you should know that you can't just click the green run button and launch the app via ADB.  You have to install it the maven way (Run As -> Maven build/install/test/whatever)

Answer (score 1):

You should open up your war file and check if you actually have two about.html files in there. Some time ago I had two web.xmls in my war files. If you actually have duplicates then you should try to exclude those files.

Maybe you have one file in your project and the duplicate is generated by the maven plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the duplicate files are coming from included dependencies, namely jetty-server and jetty-continuation which is a dependency of jetty-server.

Answer (score 0):

I also just realized that you're probably already properly using the android-maven plugin.  One other important tip: **change the scope to runtime** on the jetty dependencies.  This builds successfully for me, whereas using the default scope (compile) always threw the duplicate file in APK error.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Harlo.

Yes, I am already using the maven android plugin. Your first comment seems specific to the setup of the plugin and build process, which I believe I have done.

Your second point seems much more relevant to the problem. If I change the scope of the dependency to runtime, then I do not get the duplicate file error. However a runtime dependency is not useful to me since I have no way to reference the classes provided by jetty-server.