# OpenCV on Android Duplicate File for APK

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface

I am attempting to build an app that uses the Android port of OpenCV. I have the C++ OpenCV function written and wrapped properly, and the project builds without any errors. When I go to build a signed APK, however, I get the following error:

```
[2012-02-26 21:06:50 - PortalSentry] Found duplicate file for APK: lib/armeabi-v7a/libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so
Origin 1: C:\workspace\android_body\PortalSentry\libs\armeabi-v7a\libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so
Origin 2: C:\workspace\android_body\OpenCV-2.3.1\libs\armeabi-v7a\libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so
```

The solution that I have seen mentioned in several places is to add

```
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
```

before including the OpenCV makefile. I tried this and still get the same duplicate file error. Is there a way to explicitly tell Eclipse to not include one of these library files? I believe the reason this is happening is because I'm linking to OpenCV both from Java and C++, but the OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES line is supposed to stop the double include in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

How to solve building OpenCV Samples with native OpenCv from http://opencv.itseez.com ?

I ran in this problem myself. I used OpenCV 2.4 beta and the problem occured when building the sample tutorial, which uses native OpenCV code.

I fixed it and I want to try to explain how I went down.

I assume you build the library like this in eclipse: [Android binary package using with NDK](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html)

Both projects, the OpenCV project and the sample project are in the same Workspace. the OpenCV project is marked as Library.

Project setting differences between openCV2.3 and 2.4beta:

- 2.3:

  - project settings -> Android -> add Reference -> PathToOpenCV-2.3
  - project settings -> Java Build Path -> Projects: Add Project "OpenCV-2.3"
  - project settings -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export: "OpenCV-2.3" at top, checkbox checked
- 2.4

  - project settings -> Android -> add Reference -> PathToOpenCV-2.4beta
    other 2 settings not needed

When you do this, the Java projects do work. However, when you include these lib projects and then try to build the native samples, the `<libname>.so` files are copied and find themselves inside the sample projects folder under `/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/` with some other `*.a` files from the prebuilt OpenCV project. From there, the NDK builds the files in the `/lib` folder, which are later included in the apk file (I think).  Then, the Java part of Eclipse runs.  This detects a duplicate of the `.so` files, which find themslves in the OpenCV lib and now in your sample lib, so it denies building a new apk file. (There might be a workaround to make this with duplicate entries, I did not follow this.See [Duplicate file when deploying apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103863/duplicate-file-when-deploying-apk)).

To avoid the duplicates, I removed the option in project properties "project settings -> Android -> add Reference -> PathToOpenCV-2.4beta", the NDK then imports the libs and builds them (as the paths are set up in the Eclipse build chain from the 2nd link above), the sample knows some OpenCV from the binaries although it does not include the whole OpenCV project.

I don't know if this works when you need Java support for OpenCV too.